# printf statement printing previous printf statement

Tags: c, debugging, printing, printf

I have one of the weirdest bugs I've ever seen.

I have a simple program that prints several arrays of integers.

The arrays are sorted, then the printed ...

```
  place_in_buf(n100, 100);
  insertion(100);
  printf("\nThe number of comparisons in insertion sort for n=100 is: %d", insertion_count);
  insertion_count = 0;

  place_in_buf(n200, 200);
  insertion(200);
  printf("\nThe number of comparisons in insertion sort for n=200 is: %d", insertion_count);
  insertion_count = 0;
```

the program is seg faulting because the first print statement isn't printed until the second print statement is executed. as shown by the following debugging...

```
   95     */
   96     place_in_buf(n100, 100);
   97     insertion(100);
-> 98     printf("\nThe number of comparisons in insertion sort for n=100 is: %d", insertion_count);
   99     insertion_count = 0;
   100
   101    place_in_buf(n200, 200);
(lldb) n

Process 1139 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c96, 0x00000001000017b3 P3`insertion_comparison + 67 at HW8P3.c:99, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step over
    frame #0: 0x00000001000017b3 P3`insertion_comparison + 67 at HW8P3.c:99
   96     place_in_buf(n100, 100);
   97     insertion(100);
   98     printf("\nThe number of comparisons in insertion sort for n=100 is: %d", insertion_count);
-> 99     insertion_count = 0;
   100
   101    place_in_buf(n200, 200);
   102    insertion(200);

   ... 

   101    place_in_buf(n200, 200);
   102    insertion(200);
-> 103    printf("\nThe number of comparisons in insertion sort for n=200 is: %d", insertion_count);
   104    insertion_count = 0;
   105
   106    place_in_buf(n400, 400);
(lldb) n
The number of comparisons in insertion sort for n=100 is: 4950
Process 1139 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c96, 0x00000001000017ef P3`insertion_comparison + 127 at HW8P3.c:104, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step over
    frame #0: 0x00000001000017ef P3`insertion_comparison + 127 at HW8P3.c:104
   101    place_in_buf(n200, 200);
   102    insertion(200);
   103    printf("\nThe number of comparisons in insertion sort for n=200 is: %d", insertion_count);
-> 104    insertion_count = 0;
```

I've tried this on my local Mac and a Linux server, both are doing the same thing

I've also tried resetting my PRAM, but that was without luck as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did not read the complete post, but looks like you can use a `\n` at the end of the format string in `printf()`.

Comment: Suggest adding a `'\n'` to the end of the `printf()` or adding `fflush(stdout)`.  The source of the bug smells like it is in `place_in_buf(n100, 100);` or `insertion(100);`

Comment: no luck with the `fflush(stdout)` either

Comment: scratch that, I was compiling the wrong file lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output to `stdout` (which is used by `printf`) is by default *line buffered*, which means the buffer is flushed and actually written on newline.

Since you only print *leading* newlines and not trailing, you get the output of the previous contents in the buffer up to the newline, everything after the newline will be buffered until you call `printf` again with a newline.

You should make it a habit to use *trailing* newlines instead.